# A continuous and holomorphic function on $D^2$ that takes pure imaginary values on $S^1$ is costant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $D := \{ |z| < 1\}$ and $f : \overline{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous and holomorphic function on $D$ that takes pure imaginary values on $\partial D$. Why $f$ is constant?

From this, if you take two functions that are continuous on $\overline{D}$ and holomorphic on $D$ such that their real parts coincide on $\partial D$, why they differ for a constant?

Comment: Consider how $f(\partial D)$ winds around $f(0)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real part $u = \operatorname{Re} f$ is harmonic, and since $u = 0$ on $\partial D$, the maximum principle for harmonic functions implies that $u = 0$ on $D$. Hence $f$ takes purely imaginary values on $D$, and consequently, by Cauchy-Riemann's equations, $f$ must be constant. (Easy exercise.)

In particular, if $\operatorname{Re} f = \operatorname{Re} g$ on $\partial D$, then $h = f-g$ satisfies the above, and must be constant.

Comment: Does the maximum principle for harmonic functions require harmonicity on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ or is it only continuity on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and harmonicity on the interior?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Continuous on $\bar\Omega$, harmonic on $\Omega$ is enough.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. We require $\Omega$ to bounded though right?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes.