# Does there exist a holomorphic function with pure imaginary or real values on the boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering if there exists a holomorphic function $f(z)$ on unit disk $D$, which takes pure imaginary values on part of the boundary $|z| = 1$ and takes pure real values on the rest of the boundary, i.e.,

$\Re (f(e^{i\theta})) \equiv 0, \forall \theta\in I_1$ and $ \Im(f(e^{i\theta}))\equiv 0, \forall \theta\in I_2$ where $I_1\cap I_2=\emptyset, I_1\cup I_2=[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Is $f$ analytic on an open set containing the closed unit disc?

Comment: @copper.hat Actually, I got this question from Hilbert transform. The original problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519079/convolution-with-cotangent-function). I think these two problems are equivalent. Since the Hilbert transformed function is the conjugate function.

Comment: My same question stands...

Comment: @copper.hat, umm, I mean, I can only say that $f$ is holomorphic in unit disk according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Conjugate_function). I cannot make other assumptions on $f$. So if not, can you find a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You've been vague about how these boundary values are taken on. But suppose this $f$ is continuous on the closed disc. Show $\text { Im }f^2\equiv 0$ on the boundary. What does this tell you?

Comment: I was going to suggest to the OP to think about what $f'(z)$ and higher derivatives must look like on the unit circle for such a function $f$, but this is much more compact.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint! So $\text{Im}f^2\equiv 0$ implies that $f^2$ must be constant in the closed unit disk by Cauchy-Riemann equation and so is $f$. Am I correct?

Comment: @zdwang, you only have that the square of f has zero imaginary part *on the boundary*.

Comment: @moderator, yes but due to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818140/a-continuous-and-holomorphic-function-on-d2-that-takes-pure-imaginary-values), I think $f^2$ should be constant in the entire disk.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Thank you for the alternative approach! So you mean under the described boundary conditions, f(z) must not be infinitely differentiable right? I am not sure whether I’ve got your point.

Comment: @zdwang, I actually wanted you to pay attention to the two points where the two arcs of the unit circle would join up. What would e.g. Cauchy-Riemann look like at those points? Then do it again for the next derivative, and so forth. You should eventually hit a contradiction.

Comment: @zdwang Right. $\text { Im }f^2=0$ on $\partial D,$ which implies  $\text { Im }f^2=0$ in $D,$ which implies $f^2$ is real in $D,$ which implies $f^2$ is constant in $D,$ which implies $f$ is constant in $D.$